# Hide all product images - for store selling only virtual products

Tags: product, product-images, virtual

How can I hide or remove product image area for a company selling only virtual products?
Trying to remove or hide Thumbnail, Small Image, Base Image, And Media image, if possible.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you looking at removing the images from displaying from the front end, or for also removing images from product view in the admin area.

Comment: I would like to remove the images from displaying from the front end.  Thank you...

Comment: See the answer below plus the comment I left for removing product images within the product list and cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using local.xml file in your theme's layout folder.
Removing media from product page would look like this(Not tested, should work, if handle "product.info.media" not customized in theme):

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="product.info.media" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

<strike>Similar process can be carried out for all other places(Category and Cart pages).</strike> To remove images from category pages and cart pages, you'd need to modify the templates.

Create a copy in your theme's template folder of catalog/product/list.phtml and checkout/cart/item/default.phtml files and replace/comment img tags appropriately. This should be sufficient for simple products throughout the site as I can't recall any more default place where these images are called, if I can have the liberty of neglecting those sidebars.

Comment: You can remove the media from the product view page using the above, for product list and cart you will need to remove the images from the template files template/catalog/product/list.phtml and checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Comment: @Bobadevv, yes you are right. I'll soon update the answer.

Comment: You can consider it as your Triumph Card against Magento! !!